# How can you unlock a Sprint iPhone 6 Plus? It was paid in full without a contract

Tags: unlock, iphone

I purchased a Sprint iPhone 6 Plus 64gb off contract. I paid the full amount which was about $1,000. As of today (2014-09-24), how can we unlock the iPhone 6 Plus which is on Sprint? I am a Sprint customer.

Comment: @Buscar웃, note that off-contract is different from unlocked.  Off-contract phones are eligible to be unlocked, but aren't always sold that way.

Comment: @webmarc thanks, still when bought new and paid in full (without contract) why would be locked in first place ? Now the owner has to chase the Sprint to find a willing person to unlock it (and if). That is a dirty marketing game not pointing it out in advertisement. What is spooky with OP, Sprint does not offer full purchase price (up front pay) plans.

Comment: @Buscar웃 There is probably no hardware or part-number difference between a non-contract phone and a contract phone; the only difference is the price sold at the register.  So it makes sense from the merchants perspective to have them all carrier-locked, and leave it to the consumer to get the non-contract phone unlocked if they want to.

Comment: Sprint phones are usually sold as internationally unlocked, but not unlocked to be used on AT&T or T-Mobile here in the states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just called sprint about this and unlocking their phones in general. it goes for any phone, not just iPhone 6. it seems that sprint requires any NEW phone purchased on the account to be ACTIVE for 90 days in order to unlock it for "international" use.

So as for the iphone 6, since its released in sept, we have to wait 90 days, which is sometime in December 2014 before we can unlock it on our account to use it overseas. And NO they will not unlock it for other domestic carriers.

So if your thinking about buying the iphone 6 from sprint to flip for a profit, don't bother. This sprint 90 day active line restriction kills it. You actually have to have the iphone 6 **ACTIVE** on your line, which means you actually have to be using it before they unlock it.

Answer (score 6):

Sprint phones CANNOT normally be unlocked for use with any other carrier in the U.S., with the exception of Ting mobile, which uses the Sprint network. Additionally, both Sprint and Verizon are on CDMA networks, so any restrictions imposed on transferring is fabricated by those companies for profit. Additionally, many new phones, including iPhones work with both CDMA and GSM, the only thing stopping you from transferring is the company.

Here is a lame excuse from an actual Sprint technician:

> **Betty S:** Some Apple devices have an MSL code, while others do not, however, even unlocking the software using the MSL code will not enable these phones to operate on a domestic carriers’ network
>
> **Betty S:** Apple phones sold for use on Sprint's network are designed with an external SIM slot and sold with a SIM card to operate on Sprint's network.
>
> **Betty S:** Those devices are not enabled for use on a different domestic carrier’s network because the Sprint-specific CDMA requirements are hardcoded in the firmware of the device and downloaded for operation on Sprint’s network and specific frequencies.
>
> **Betty S:** This is true even within Sprint’s Network, for instance between Sprint and Virgin Mobile. These phones, if sold through a Sprint channel were not engineered as a universal Domestic device.
>
> **Betty S:** Even if these devices have MSL codes that can be unlocked, the SIM cannot be enabled for use on a domestic carriers’ network.

While the firmware being different is true, it is only that way to stop customers from leaving with their devices.

Comment: what about for international use? i purchased a sprint iphone 6 plus and paid full price. would i be able to just unlock it for international use? say if i wanted to sell it on ebay to someone overseas, does sprint lock the phone to your sprint account even if they unlock it for interantional use?

Answer (score 2):

[Unlocking Sprint in the USA](http://www.sprint.com/legal/unlocking_policy.html) is not possible currently and **will not result in any benefit**, so your best option is to bring it back and get your money if you do not like to be in the cage.

> If you’re using a Sprint prepaid affiliate, like Virgin or Boost,
>   Sprint currently **cannot unlock** those devices. Supposedly help is on
>   its way — as these policies are in violation of the [CITA’s unlocking
>   agreement](https://gigaom.com/2014/07/25/congress-passes-cellphone-unlocking-bill-obama-likely-to-sign-it-into-law/), new, more consumer-friendly policies should be in place by
>   February 11, 2015.

For [International see this information](http://shop.sprint.com/mysprint/services_solutions/category.jsp?catId=service_international&catName=International%20Services).

Basically how the International works is true Sprint agreement for Roaming:

Means they have a contract with

> [countless GSM **Roaming** and International CDMA Roaming partners.](http://www.sprint.com/popups/pop-gprsCarriers.html)

**So what does all that means to you**:

If you are in the USA then

- Sprint will not unlock the phone so you can use it on Verizon (while on the same technology (CDMA), the reason is not technical it is business.
- Sprint will unlock the phone for International use with GSM? but will not allow you to use ATT, T-Mobile in the USA. The reason again is business and not technical (even so if your Sprint iPhone has the capability).
- Sprint is not in compliance with the USA law that becomes active in Feb. 2015, and they know that. They will change they company business policy from that date forward to comply with the new law, but as far I know it will not be backwards compatible (for iPhone bought before that date).

Answer (score 2):

I just bought a iPhone 6 Model A1586 (Sprint) today at an US Apple Store. I put in my T-Mobile Germany SIM before turning it on and it works fine.

As a Sprint customer all you can ask is an unlock for international use as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that you have a **iPhone** that is **useless for you**.

From http://www.sprint.com/legal/unlocking_policy.html

> Not all Sprint devices have an MSL code or a locking function that can be unlocked by Sprint (e.g., Apple devices cannot be unlocked to accept another domestic carrier's SIM card).

The confusion is that they have to "unlock for international" use by law. Often online it's mentioned as "unlocking".

Answer (score 0):

ontact Sprint Customer Care by dialing *2 from your Sprint mobile device or call 888-211-4727, if you bought as full price and no contract with sprint, they should give you the MSL code according their policy (Requesting the Master Subsidy Lock code):
http://www.sprint.com/legal/unlocking_policy.html

if you have contract with sprint, you want to unlock it, you need to pay remain money to Sprint, if you have no money and you want to use the Sprint Iphone6 for international travel (use other operators' SIM card), just wait 90 days.

Answer (score -1):

You need to contact Sprint.  If the phone is locked to their network, they can provide instructions and a code to unlock it.

Comment: Have you done this yourself?

Comment: @MichaelStoner No.

Answer (score -2):

I bought an Iphone 6 from Sprint paying the full price too. But in my case is to use in Brasil. I received a recommendation from a apple store employer to not use in the first power on the chip of Spring, this will let the iphone unlocked to use in others country except USA.

Hope this help anyone...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Can you clarify?